# jQuery selector, syntax or bug?

Tags: jquery, syntax, jquery-selectors

This is weird I have markup like this

```
<div id='div1'>
  <ul id='ul1'>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
  <div id='div2'>
    <ul id='ul2'>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

in jquery I have a selector like this:

```
var el = $('#div2');
var liList = el.children('ul:first > li');
```

That should return the second set of li's but it returns the first set. 
But if I do this:

```
var el = $('#div2');
var liList = el.children('ul:first').children('li');
```

It returns the first set. Any ideas what's going on?

This made me take a double take because the 1st set of li's aren't even children of `div2`

I can obviously change my code to the latter, but is it a bug or am I just not writing my selector correctly?

**UPDATE:**
I was running jquery 1.4.1 and using jsfiddle like was suggested below showed different results with 1.4.2(the closest option to my config)  and 1.4.4. So it seems like it was partly I wrote a wrong selector as indicated by Rocket and the jquery team fixed a bug that was in 1.4.1. :)

Gotta love StackOverflow :)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code. If you click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2YEHj/) you can see your code in action, and the former example matches the correct li items.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I made a fiddle too but you beat me to the comment.

Comment: @Alex, not exactly.  The first example returns the 'ul', whereas the second returns the 'li's.

Comment: `.children()` returns 'immediate children'.

Comment: Alex and Tesserex. I looked at your fiddle but it still isn't right. It shows all li's instead of only div2's. As a clarification, my question might be what SHOULD the first selector return?

Comment: My fiddle returns the `ul#ul2`, which isn't quite what he's asking about, but it certainly doesn't return the first set of `li` elements.

Comment: Neither selector returns ul1's lis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.children()` returns 'immediate children'.  `ul2` and its `li`s are children of `div2`, but ONLY `ul2` is an 'immediate child'.  To get all the `li`s, you need to use the second one.

The `li`s are 'immediate children' of their respective `ul`.

I hope this makes sence.

```
var el = $('#div2');
var ul2 = el.children('ul:first > li'); // retuns ul2, because it's an immediate child
                                       // the '> li' doesn't do anything
var liList = ul2.children('li');  // this will return all of ul2's lis
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gGgZt/)

Comment: ok so how could I return the second set of li's using only one method(without chaining)?

Comment: @Jose: `var liList = el.find('ul:first > li');`

Comment: It would seem as though `el.children('ul:first > li')` should return an empty set, since the immediate children need to match the selector provided. Since the targeted element in the selector is `li`, it should find no matches. Seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

Is it something to do with DIV2 being inside DIV1?

Comment: why would it? I select div2 first and then ask for it's children. Not only does it not return it's children that match the selector, it returns elements that aren't it's own children

Comment: Just a thought - there is no reason it shouldn't work, but as you were musing if it were a bug - bugs sometimes happen for odd reasons ;-)

Comment: @Babkier - yeh i know, dont have enough rep to comment on anything yet though :(